# How to make Eclipse to format JSP code properly?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, code-formatting

I use code formatting command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) a lot in Eclipse IDE. While this works pretty well for Java / CSS source codes, the JSP formatting is just *sucks*.

Is there any plug-in available to make the JSP formatting better in Eclipse IDE? By formatting I mean proper indenting of JSP/HTML tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search with Google turns up [this](http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-11.html) part of MyEclipse Enterprise Workbench.

But a quick, if obvious, question: do you have the J2EE tools installed?

Comment: @MyEclipse - Isn't it commercial? :)

Yes. I have the JEE tools installed.

Comment: This screen just shows the WTP (which is part of Java EE tools, yes). Besides, MyEclipse isn't much different from Eclipse nowadays.

Comment: once you press Ctrl+Shift+F in a properly indented JSP code, you'll feel what i'm going through. :-D

Comment: Yes, I know. I never use it in JSP as well. There is afaik no plugin which does it *right*.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is sucks for java also!
It can not detect line code size dynamic and breaking code to Irrational parts,for jsp also in other Ide's like Intelliji editor detects

```
    <tags>
  .......<tag2>
```

in understandable format that you can track tag start and end point by your eyes ,
But unfortunately in eclipse you can just say editor to cut off jsp in specific size ,
We have a idiom ,Drink soup as you paid!

Answer (score 0):

So what I found out was, that eclipse reformat's jsp files by **methods** not line by line. Only if it can reformat the entire method properly it will try. For example if you have this kind of code in the method.

```
+ message
    + "</p></div><div class='modal-footer'>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-outline
 btn-flat pull-right' data-dismiss='modal'>"
+ code + "</button>
</div>");
```

The refactor wont happen.

You need to make it to

```
+ message
    + "</p></div><div class='modal-footer'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-outline btn-flat pull-right' data-dismiss='modal'>"
+ code + "</button> </div>");
```

And now refactor will work. To this

```
+ message
+ "</p></div><div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-outline btn-flat pull-right' data-dismiss='modal'>"
+ code + "</button></div>");
```