# Code formatter for JSPs?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, formatter

My team uses Eclipse, Spring and JSPs.

We have code formatters for Java which work perfectly but our JSP pages are a horror to maintain in such a large team when we have no unified formatter. Is there a formatter out there that caters for JSP pages with HTML, Javascript and Java?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, you are unhappy with the formatting capabilities of Eclipse for JSPs.

I think the situation is best summed up by @BalusC's comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/3469289/139985.

> *"There is, AFAIK, no plugin which does it **right**."*

The fundamental problem is that the JSP level can be injecting arbitrary chunks of HTML or Javascript into the document at runtime.  A formatter needs to know (at least) the structure of the injected stuff ... in order indent the static part of the JSP correctly (from the perspective of the reader).  But that would require the formatter to *understand* what is going to be injected.  That is impractical.

---

The real answer is to change your team culture.  Get everyone to agree on a standard set of formatting principles / rules, and make it everyone's responsibility to conform to the rules.  If people resist, appoint a code quality Czar, and institute mandatory code reviews.  If people don't like *that* ... there are always other people looking for jobs.